# How to migrate Alamofire router class to Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3

Does anybody know how to change this entire approach to Swift 3? At this moment I have something very similar to this working OK on Swift 2.2 but now I'm trying to change that to Swift 3.

I am getting some errors with the "URLRequestConvertible", with the Alamofire.Method (that I changed to HTTPMethod and now is working) and also with the parameter encoding, besides that I'm not conforming the entire protocol.

I'm waiting for guidance from engineers at Alamofire, but I am looking to see what I can accomplish in the meantime.

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
static let baseURLString = "http://example.com"
static var OAuthToken: String?

case CreateUser([String: AnyObject])
case ReadUser(String)
case UpdateUser(String, [String: AnyObject])
case DestroyUser(String)

var method: Alamofire.Method {
    switch self {
    case .CreateUser:
        return .POST
    case .ReadUser:
        return .GET
    case .UpdateUser:
        return .PUT
    case .DestroyUser:
        return .DELETE
    }
}

var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .CreateUser:
        return "/users"
    case .ReadUser(let username):
        return "/users/\(username)"
    case .UpdateUser(let username, _):
        return "/users/\(username)"
    case .DestroyUser(let username):
        return "/users/\(username)"
    }
}

// MARK: URLRequestConvertible

var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
    let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

    if let token = Router.OAuthToken {
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }

    switch self {
    case .CreateUser(let parameters):
        return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .UpdateUser(_, let parameters):
        return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    default:
        return mutableURLRequest
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting same problem. Did you find any solution for this.

 Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### EDITED for Alamofire 4.0.0 release (updated `URLRequestConvertible` protocol with throwing capabilities):

A **lot** has changed in Swift 3 and you should first really read up on all the changes, maybe starting at http://swift.org. Here's the fixed code:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "http://example.com"
    static var OAuthToken: String?
    
    case createUser([String: AnyObject])
    case readUser(String)
    case updateUser(String, [String: AnyObject])
    case destroyUser(String)
    
    var method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .createUser:
            return .post
        case .readUser:
            return .get
        case .updateUser:
            return .put
        case .destroyUser:
            return .delete
        }
    }
    
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .createUser:
            return "/users"
        case .readUser(let username):
            return "/users/\(username)"
        case .updateUser(let username, _):
            return "/users/\(username)"
        case .destroyUser(let username):
            return "/users/\(username)"
        }
    }
    
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = URL(string: Router.baseURLString)!
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        
        if let token = Router.OAuthToken {
            urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }
        
        switch self {
        case .createUser(let parameters):
            return try Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        case .updateUser(_, let parameters):
            return try Alamofire.URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        default:
            return urlRequest
        }
    }
}
```

The main changes for Swift 3 are :

- `enum` cases are now lowercase and you should adopt it too.
- Variable names now start with lowercase, even if it's an abbreviation like "URL". That why the protocol requires `var urlRequest` and not `var URLRequest` (and it would conflict with the next point)
- Bye-bye `NS` prefix in many places. `NSURLRequest` and `NSMutableURLRequest` are now `URLRequest`, `NSURL` is `URL`, etc.
- How you name your functions and parameters is now a lot less redundant and more natural. See for example how `URLByAppendingPathComponent` has changed.

And as for Alamofire v4 :

- There's a new `ParameterEncoding` protocol to encoding parameters yourself is different but more versatile
- MANY other changes which have no impact here but you sure have to read about them too.

And final word of advice : avoid migrating to unreleased versions of a programming language or API if it's time-sensitive. Swift 3 won't budge much but Alamofire still might! For example the `ParameterEncoding` protocol is only two days old! (EDIT: and indeed it changed since, now in its final version above)

Cheers

Comment: The errors that i'm getting are: `Type 'Router' does not conform to protocol 'URLRequestConvertible'` and also what is the equivalent for `Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.json.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0` and `Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.urlEncodedInURL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: URLParameters).0`in swift 3?

Comment: Thanks for the help :D.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the `try!` on the `encode` call. There's a mismatch there between the `encode` call throwing, and the `URLRequestConvertible` protocol not allowing `urlRequest` to throw or to return nil, and I don't think the `try!` is the right way to go about it. That is just allowing the code to compile, but discarding the safety of Swift in runtime.

Comment: Neither do I. The scope of the question was to help migration, aka get it to compile. Having the `ProgressEncoding` protocol throw is a new addition that changes from the behaviour in Alamofire 3.4. I'm glad to help the OP implement error handling with a `do {} catch{}` but I don't know what the desired behaviour would be in the OP's app.

Comment: @GabrielCandia make sure that `var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest` is `var urlRequest: URLRequest` since that property is required (and the name has changed).