# How to use `ParameterEncoding` together with `URLRequestConvertible`?

Tags: alamofire, swift3

I was migrating my code to Swift 3 and updated Alamofire to the swift 3 branch.
There, the suggested way of handling parameter encoding is to use one of the new `ParameterEncoding` conforming structs, such as `URLEncoding`, that has an `encode` method.

The problem is that this method now **throws**, which makes sense, but the `URLRequestConvertible` protocol still expects a `urlRequest` property that returns the constructed request, so we can't just call `encode` and return the result, nor return a nil.

What is the suggested way of handling this, if the router can't fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how Alamofire handles it internally :

```
open func request(
    _ urlString: URLStringConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: [String: String]? = nil)
    -> DataRequest
{
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(urlString: urlString, method: method, headers: headers)

    do {
        let encodedURLRequest = try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        return request(resource: encodedURLRequest)
    } catch {
        let request = self.request(resource: urlRequest)
        request.delegate.error = error
        return request
    }
}
```

Basically, it uses the request without the parameters. I don't know how far it can be used in your own implementation (or [How to migrate Alamofire router class to Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412700/migrating-alamofire-router-class-to-swift-3) 's OP).
I'd suggest filing an issue with Alamofire if this is not possible. The new `ParameterEncoding` is literally two days old ([PR 1465](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/1465)) and still in the 4.0.0 beta cycle.
In any case, using `URLEncoding.encode()` seldom fails if you set your own `URLRequest` because the only error thrown is when there's no URL provided with the request.

EDIT: Here you go, 4.0.0 released, and the issue's been fixed! ([PR 1505](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/1505)). There have been other changes to `URLRequestConvertible` but all's in the Migration Guide and README.