# Alamofire 4.0 Router Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlrequest

I'm in the process of converting to `Swift 3.0`, and have a custom `Router` class for `Alamofire`. My code is as follows:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

    case get(query: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?)
    case post(query: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?)
    case put(query: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?)
    case delete(query: String, params: [String: AnyObject]?)

    var urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {

        // Default to GET
        var httpMethod: HTTPMethod = .get

        let (path, parameters): (String, [String: AnyObject]?) = {
            switch self {
            case .get(let query, let params):
                // Set the request call
                httpMethod = .get
                // Return the query
                return (query, params)
            case .post(let query, let params):
                // Set the request call
                httpMethod = .post
                // Return the query
                return (query, params)
            case .put(let query, let params):
                // Set the request call
                httpMethod = .put
                // Return the query
                return (query, params)
            case .delete(let query, let params):
                // Set the request call
                httpMethod = .delete
                // Return the query
                return (query, params)
            }
        }()


        // Create the URL Request
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest
        if let url =  URL(string: Globals.BASE_URL + path) {
            urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        } else {
            urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        }

        // set header fields
        if let key = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Globals.NS_KEY_SESSION) {
            urlRequest.setValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-XX-API")
        }

        // Add user agent
        if let userAgent = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Globals.NS_KEY_USER_AGENT) {
            urlRequest.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        }

        // Set the HTTP method
        urlRequest.httpMethod = httpMethod.rawValue

        // Set timeout interval to 20 seconds
        urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 20

        return Alamofire.URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest as! URLRequestConvertible, with: parameters)
    }

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    }
}
```

This is giving me an error stating `Type of expression is ambiguious without more context` at `Alamofire.URLEncoding()`. What does this mean?

Within the `Alamofire` docs at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#parameter-encoding-protocol, they have the code

```
public protocol ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nearly a duplicate of [How to migrate Alamofire router class to Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412700/how-to-migrate-alamofire-router-class-to-swift-3/39414724)
Check it out and you'll see how to use the new `ParameterEncoding` and especially that `URLRequestConvertible` is now implemented with a `func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest` and not a `var` anymore.

Comment: Thanks implementing as the `func` and not `var` did help.