# Response<AnyObject, NSError> undeclared type in Alamofire4/Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm going through old code updating to the new iOS and Swift version and thus Alamofire version and its been a giant headache thus far. I have this code which I've simplified

```
fileprivate func fetchOuttings(_ type: MyType, callback: ((Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> ())?) {

    /* ... */

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
        if let _callback = callback {
            _callback(response)
        }
    })

}
```

In the function signature after the Swift3/Alamofire4 update I'm not getting 'Use of undeclared type Response' and I can't figure out how to fix this. I've been looking all through the [Alamofire 4 migration](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) but can't find anything. And one have ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Response<AnyObject, NSError>` is now `DataResponse<Any>`. Take a look at the [new implementation of `responseJSON`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift#L530-L542).

Answer (score 1):

Now it has changed to `DataResponse` as @Rob Napier said. as an example if your want `responseString` it should look like this

`DataResponse<String>`and also, it will handle any error in `.failure` part. you have to follow more in new `Alamoire` . better to refer their docs in github [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and also, if you want to know abour new `Router` class implemention go with [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412700/how-to-migrate-alamofire-router-class-to-swift-3).